# Checking keyboard state

Tags: go

I can't seem to find a cross-platform library with Go that supports checking the state of the keyboard.

I'd rather not use something so heavy as Qt as it makes it quite hard to cross-compile and the GUI elements are very simple. If anybody could point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Thanks a ton.

Stuff I've tried:

https://mattn.github.io/go-gtk/

https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3

https://github.com/andlabs/ui (My favorite thus far, very lightweight.)
If there is something I could use alongside this, that would be great as well.

EDIT:

Hey guys, a few months later just wanted to give an update. I ended up going the Qt route. Therecipe's bindings are pretty solid, aside from a few bugs. Getting proper keyboard input to put it short was nothing more than a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found GLFW to be pretty straightforward to get set up.
https://github.com/go-gl/glfw

If you want something even more cross platform, try out
https://github.com/goxjs/glfw

It has conditional compilation which lets you compile on desktop platforms normally, but also to gopherjs so you can run the same code in a browser canvas.

Here a keyboard handler package I made with it:
https://github.com/Omustardo/gome/blob/master/input/keyboard/keyboard.go

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I use GLFW quite a bit with C++ so I'm pretty used to it. Maybe that's the route I want to go.